# Redirect oldsite.com to new.oldsite.com, and sub.oldsite.com to new.oldsite.com/sub/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a situation where we've redesigned a site and have moved it to a new domain. The old site has a few client subdomains that we need to redirect to the new domain, but to folders that we will explicitly specify. Note that the new domain is actually a subdomain of the old domain, so not sure how that complicates anything, if at all.

For example, `oldsite.com` currently redirects all request to `new.oldsite.com` with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.oldsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.oldsite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I also want to redirect some specific subdomains to folders of `new.oldtsite.com`, like `subdomain.oldsite.com` to `new.oldsite.com/subdomain/`. There also the likelihood that the old subdomain and the new directory will have different names (`subdomain.oldsite.com` to `new.oldsite.com/subdomain-name/`. :-/

I've attempted to duplicate this rule for the subdomain to folder redirect, but that just hijacks all redirects.

I will give you a virtual high-five if you can spot me a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules from specific to generic. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.oldsite.com/subdomain-name/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.oldsite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**EDIT:** To redirect `any.oldsite.com/foo` to `new.oldsite.com/any/foo`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.oldsite.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Awesome! o/\o @anubhava, that works great for redirecting those subdomains, now is there a way to have a catch-all for other subdomains and redirect them to `new.oldsite.com`?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes that can also be done, let me edit my answer.